# C++ urdl library linker error

Tags: c++, xcode, linker-errors

I'm using urdl as a header only library. I did the steps for building as listed on their website, but I still get some undefined symbols. I think the linker are unable to see the function definitions in the .ipp files, but I don't know why. Anyone know what I'm doing wrong? I'm using XCode and clang. I use urdl to get an istream to parse xml for those wondering. This is the code I've written so far using the urdl library. Any answer would be highly appreciated, thanks!

```
urdl::istream xmlStream("http://www.blahblah.com/blah.xml");
```

[image: error message]

Comment: This is not a linker error, although your linker configuration could be incorrect also. You need to specify include path correctly to get around the 'Undefined Symbols' problem.

Comment: Hey, thank you for your response. I think I've set the include path correctly. I've set "header search paths" to the usr/local/include where i've put urdl. The compiler doesn't complain when I include urdl either.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone else who comes across this, when using as header only you need to add URDL_HEADER_ONLY=1 to your compiler's preprocessor definitions so the ipp files get included.